# How to use the correct WebP encoding for Wikimedia Commons?

Tags: codec, animation, webp

I am trying to encode some cyclical graphic animations for Wikimedia Commons. The following article says, "The image format WebP that is based on VP8 is supported on commons. It supports both lossless and lossy image compression."

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:File_types

Which tool will allow me to use this particular subset of the WebP codec? How do I set up and configure the tool on Windows?

I uploaded [test file 1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_system_orrery_outer_planets.webp) and [test file 2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_system_orrery_inner_planets.webp) to Commons and the thumbnails are not rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use WebP on Wikimedia Commons, you don't have to worry about any subsets of WebP.

1. Go to [WebP downloads repository](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html) and download "libwebp-1.1.0-windows-x64.zip" (or newer).
2. Open the downloaded file and locate "bin" folder in it.
3. If your input are GIF animations, extract "gif2webp.exe" to a suitable folder. If your input are standalone images, extract "img2webp.exe" to a suitable folder.
4. Run the extracted tool with `-h` parameter to see its help. The default compression of both tools is lossless.

Comment: I added some test files to my question. They are not rendering at all.

Comment: The thumbnails are not rendering rather.

Comment: @posfan12 The test files themselves are rendering OK. Not rendering the thumbnails on Commons seems like a bug in Commons.

Answer (score 0):

Second command needs to be run as admin

```
scoop bucket add nonportable
scoop install icaros-np
```

https://github.com/TheRandomLabs/scoop-nonportable/blob/master/bucket/icaros-np.json